# How can I limit a log file to a certain number of most recent logs?

Tags: files, logs, limit, size

I know that you can limit the size of a file in respect to bytes, but I was wondering if there was a way to limit the number of logs within the file to, for example, the most recent 200 logs.

Comment: What do you mean with «the number of logs within the file»? Do you mean the number of log *lines* in a *text* log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logrotate](http://linuxconfig.org/logrotate-8-manual-page#h5-configuration-file) has the *rotate* parameter that specifies how many logs to save.